# Update Batch without constant looping

Tags: batch-file

How do i create a script that wont constantly reloop to check if changes is enabled?

```
:0
SET CHANGES=<CHECK.TXT
:1
IF %CHANGES% GTR 0 GOTO DONE
(TIMEOUT /T 1 >NUL)
GOTO 1
:DONE
ECHO CHANGES ENABLED: %CHANGES%
PAUSE >NUL
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complete EDIT (I misinterpreted your problem):

```
@echo off

for %%i in (t.t) do set oldstamp=%%~ti

:loop
for %%i in (t.t) do set newstamp=%%~ti
if not "%newstamp%"=="%oldstamp%" goto :done
timeout /t 1 >nul
goto :loop

:done
echo file has changed
```

Comment: that would not work.. we need to get a message when CHECK.TXT is changed :)

Comment: hey again :)
so we still have "timeout /t 1 >nul" which is the major problem.. if we could find a way to replace timeout with another command so it could check without having a loop at 1 millisecond.

Comment: simply a constant not flooding check

Comment: `for /l %%i in (1,1,10) do (echo.>nul)` has a delay of about 1-2 ms - may be dependent of many things you cannot influence.